# Integrating json web token in oauth20

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, gmail-api

I am trying to create an api where user can sign up with an email or can sign in with google, I use json web token for authentication and oauth20, the problem is, can, I pass a jwt with oauth?

I have tried passing it and, I get a token if, I console log, but how do, I pass it to the user, like can i some way attach it to the req.user object in the cb by oauth or something like that?

I am doing this in the google strategy:

```
 async (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => {

   const userCheck = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

 if (userCheck) {
        const payload = {
          user: {
            id: userCheck.id
          }
        };

        jwtToken.sign(
          payload,
          config.get("jwtSecret"),
          { expiresIn: 360000 },
          (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            //   console.log(token);
            return res.json({ token });
          },
          cb(null, userCheck)
        );
```

My routes are protected like this:

```
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res)=>{
...some code
    }
```

where auth is a middle ware function

This is the Auth middleware function:

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

```
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  // If no token found


 if (!token)
 {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "User not authorized" });
  }

  // Set token to user

 try {
    const decoded = jwtToken.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));

     req.user = decoded.user;
  } 

 catch (err)
 {
    res.
status(401)
.json({ msg: "User not authenticated, please login or sign up" });
  }
  next();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you need to pass sign the token in the `passport.serializeUser` and then send the it with a redirection in response of the redirect url.

The serialize user function:

```
passport.serializeUser(async (user, cb) => {
  const payload = {
    user: {
      id: user.id
    }
  };
  token = jwtToken.sign(payload, config.get("jwtSecret"), {
    expiresIn: 360000
  });
  console.log("serialize");
  cb(null, user.id);
});
```

The redirection route:

```
router.get(
  "/google/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("google", { sessionStorage: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/" + token);
  }
);
```